# Deconvolution of a mean-preserving spread

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-functions, deconvolution

**Context**

I have been working on proving the existence of a mathematical object. After trying several things, I think that if I can show the following, an important step towards proving existence will be completed.

**The Problem**

Consider a random variable (r.v.) $X$ with full support on $\mathbb{R}$ and a continuous, strictly increasing function $f_1:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

I define for $a\in(0,1)$ the r.v. $$Y_1=(1-a)X+af_1(X).$$
The distribution of $Y_1$ is the same as the distribution of the sum of two independent random variables: $Z_1$ and $\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is distributed according to a Gaussian $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, i.e,
$$P(Y_1\leq x)=P(Z_1+\varepsilon\leq x)\qquad\text{all }x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
(That is, $Z_1$ is the outcome of deconvolving $Y_1$ using a Gaussian "transfer function".)

Similarly, consider the continuous, strictly increasing function $f_2:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and the r.v.
$$Y_2=(1-a)X+af_2(X).$$

I am looking for sufficient conditions that $f_2$ needs to satisfy so that $Y_2$
has the same distribution as that of a sum of two independent random variables: $Z_2$ and $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, i.e., 
$$P(Y_2\leq x)=P(Z_2+\varepsilon\leq x)\qquad\text{all }x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

In particular, I would like to show that $f_2$ being a mean preserving spread of $f_1$ is a sufficient condition.

**My thoughts**

I conjecture that if (the distribution of) $f_2(X)$ is a mean-preserving spread of (the distribution of) $f_1(X)$ then the tails of $Y_2$ should be at least as "fat" as the tails of $Y_1$ and, therefore, a deconvolution with the Gaussian would be possible. I am not entirely sure that I only need to worry about the tails of the distribution, though.

**Update**

Working on my conjecture, I managed to bring the problem closer to the description of the title.

Call $W_1:=f_1(X)$ and $W_2:=f_2(X)$.

Then, that $W_2$ is a mean-preserving spread of $W_1$, means that there exists a random variable $Q$ with $\mathbb{E}[Q|W_1=w_1]=0$ (for all $w_2\in\mathbb{R}$) such that
$$W_2=W_1+Q.$$
From this, we get that
$$(1-a)X+aW_2=(1-a)X+aW_1+aQ\Rightarrow \\\boxed{Y_2=Y_1+aQ.}$$
Notice that since $Y_1$ and $W_1$ are deterministic and injective functions of $X$, $\mathbb{E}[Q|Y_1=y_1]=0$ for all $y_1\in\mathbb{R}$.

Therefore, **$Y_2$ is a mean-preserving spread of $Y_1$.**

Now we know that $Y_1$ is equal in distribution to
$$Y_1\stackrel{d}{=} Z_1+\varepsilon$$
with $R_1\bot \varepsilon$.
All that is left to show is that there exists a r.v. $Z_2\bot\varepsilon$ such that 
$$Y_2\stackrel{d}{=} Z_2+\varepsilon.$$

Perhaps this is not true in general but might hold for $Q$ in some class. It would be good to identify such a class.